# I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and now ShadowProtect says it's not activated

Tags: windows-8.1

After I upgraded my Windows 8.0 system to Windows 8.1 RTM, ShadowProtect 5.0.4 says it is not activated. It was activated and working before I upgraded. How can I fix it?

I know I could try to re-activate it, but that will burn up an activation and they are pretty strict about that. At least it won't be an automatic process if I have to contact them to fix the activation problem.

Comment: You can also simply report the problem to the company and ask for assistance

Comment: @Ramhound - Indeed that is a fine idea, but you would have to wait for them to get back to you. Alternatively, you could do a web search for [windows 8.1 upgrade shadowprotect activation](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+8.1+upgrade+shadowprotect+activation), where this page with a couple of possible solutions is already the first search result. :-) That's why Stack Exchange encourages us to post questions like this along with the answers when we've already found a solution to a problem.

Comment: I didn't say this was a bad question. Sometimes you simply have to deactivate a product and activate. If the company gives you a hard time you simply explain why you had to do it. Its their software that is the problem not you activating their software.  Also didn't realize you answered your own question

Comment: @Ramhound - Ah, my fault then, I should have made it more clear that I was posting both the question and the answer. As it happened, it was late in the evening when I discovered the problem and I wanted a way to take care of it right then.

Answer (score 3):

you can virtual boot your backup image, launch shadowprotect from the VM, and deactivate from there.

Comment: Interesting idea - does it actually work? Does ShadowProtect stay activated when you boot a virtual boot a physical drive? Great trick if it does, that's really good to know. In my case it was simpler to just go ahead and swap the disks since that's so easy with a ThinkPad.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a backup image of your hard drive before upgrading Windows and made sure that you can boot from either the old or new drive (always a good idea!), then you can temporarily swap back in your backup drive with the pre-upgrade Windows 8.0 system and boot that up. Then deactivate ShadowProtect and shut down. Swap back in your upgraded Windows 8.1 drive and you'll have a new activation available.

Or avoid the hassle by deactivating ShadowProtect before upgrading Windows, then reactivate afterward. (In other words, do like I say, not like I did!)